# While using Flurry Analytics in iOS app I got error "Terminated due to memory issue" and memory utilization increase rapidly

Tags: ios, swift, flurry-analytics

When I add flurry analytics in my iOS app. Then my app memory utilization increase rapidly and app will terminate by showing this error message

> "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue".

And when I remove flurry session then my app running properly
Check my code below that I have used to add flurry analytics.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let builder = FlurrySessionBuilder.init()
            .withLogLevel(FlurryLogLevelAll)
            .withCrashReporting(true)
            .withSessionContinueSeconds(2)
        Flurry.startSession("My_key", with: builder)

}
```

Comment: What version of the SDK?

Comment: I am using flurry version 9.3.1 and I have install Flurry SDK by using pod file "pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'"

Comment: Can you post a screenshot from 'Instruments' showing the leak?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise flurry with a delay, You might have used a some third party SDK that might be taking too long to initiate

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { 
    //Initialise here
}
```